# Is it possible to style a menu differently on different "pages" in Vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js

I am quite new to Vue & encountered a problem with having a common component - **menu** - but needing to style it differently on the "TOP page" and all the other "pages".

```
<template>
  <div>
    <menu></menu>
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <router-view>TOP page and all the other pages</router-view>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

I need to apply different CSS (background, link color, etc.) to the "TOP page". Is it all possible?

Comment: are you rendering this on each page or in a base template? e.g. you could pass it a prop of what its current page is and set that as a css class.

Comment: just make the menu as a separate `SFC` component and styled that menu under style `scoped` tag

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is to create a computed property called `isTop` that will return true if the user is on the "Top page."

If `menu` here is a subcomponent, you can pass it a prop:

```
<menu :isTop='isTop'>
```

And then use Vue's conditional class syntax within the child component to dynamically select the correct CSS class based on the value of `isTop`:

```
// Template of child component:
<div :class='[{"menuTop": isTop}, {"menuGeneral": !isTop}]'>
...
</div>
```

If you actually mean to use the `<menu>` HTML tag, you can use similar syntax directly on it, without a child component:

```
<menu :class='[{"menuTop": isTop}, {"menuGeneral": !isTop}]'></menu>
```

In either case, your computed property will look something like this:

```
computed: {
  isTop: function() {
    // how you determine whether you're on the "Top page" is outside the scope of this question.
    // for example, if you're using Vue Router, you could compare the current route with a route for the Top page.
    // return true if you are on the "Top page" and return false if not.
  }
}
```

And your style block will be something like this:

```
<style>
  .menuTop {
    color: blue;
  }
  .menuGeneral{
    color: green;
  }
</style>
```